# reading CSV,XLX and Xlxs file with text between the data

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have a monthly  figures in excel sheet but every week comes with total and below each week there is a summary of the weekly figures I added a screen shoot  of an example.

I want to read this file into R with out the first few line (I have done that using SKIP) and without the summary which is at the end of each week. In some file they combined two weeks in one summary.

hint I have 350 files in this format so i can't go through them one by one.

[image]

## col1#

Comment: Please do not poste pictures. Poste copy'n'pasteable sample data and expected output. You tagged this with `sql-server`? Why not use `VBA` within Excel to prepare your data? Provide some more details, what you are trying to achieve. Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hi thank you very much for your respond i am i am new to this  and have no idea hoe to post a question here (sorry ) however,i have some experience in using R/SQL, i have never used VBA, and i have a round 350  files to go through before import them into SQL DB

Comment: Use the [`tidyxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyxl/index.html) package for Excel files. `readLines()` or `readr::read_lines()` plus manual data surgery for CSV

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from a specific range like this.

```
library(xlsx)
# first example subset; call it ss1
# assume first row is not a header; otherwise requires header = T
ss1 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/your_path/test.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, rowIndex = 4:5, colIndex = 2:3)

# second example subset; call it ss2
# just the same except worksheet index = 2
ss2 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/your_path/test.xlsx", sheetIndex = 2, rowIndex = 4:5, colIndex = 2:3)
```

Otherwise, if I was you, I'd create a small VBA script to get the data straightened out in Excel, like copy/paste the relevant data sets to a new sheet, or workbook.  Then, use R to import the data from your newly cleaned up data set.

Comment: thank you Ryguy for your answer, the range of the weeks in the sheet changes all the time. for example i don't have a fix starting row for the weeks data in the excel sheet. i have never ever used VBA script can you suggest any useful VBA scripts

Comment: Well, I gave you what you needed.  Did you actually try it?  I don't think so.  Try is and see if you can get it working.  If you have questions, you can post to the Excel-VBA discussion forum here, and there is a VBA discussion forum here too.  If you develop some decent skills, and some decent Excel/VBA skills, you can do some amazing things!

Answer (score 0):

I'm at work now and I can't see your image.  Almost everything is blocked from my office.  It's a miracle that I can even do any work at all.  Anyway, an I recall, you had a bunch of blank rows, right.  Run the macro below to copy all NON-blank rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2.  Then, from Sheet2, load your data into R.

```
Sub CopyNonBlanks()
   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   'MsgBox (LastRow)
   'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
   With Worksheets("Sheet2")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("Sheet1")
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

Then . . .

```
# read in the worksheet named Sheet2
mydata <- read.xlsx("c:/myexcel.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet2")
```